# Remover P com Jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma parte do site que é gerenciável, e esse gerenciador cria um `<p>` automaticamente. Eu não quero esse `<p>`. Como faço para remover apenas a tag `<p>` sem o conteúdo que há dentro.

```html
<li class="margin-bottom-8">
  <img src="images/iconPhoneGreen.png" class="margin-left-2 margin-right-7"><p>descricaoSYS</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use o método [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/).

```
$('p > *').unwrap();
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cv7yrekz/)</kbd>

Comment: +1. Não conhecia essa função.

Comment: +1, também não conhecia.

Comment: Fui testar e não funcionou =/

Comment: @FelipeStoker É algo [assim](http://jsfiddle.net/3qn3b94r/) que você quer?

Comment: @Qmechanic73 exato, só que comigo não funcionou oO. https://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/kkhsLz11/ no caso, o P vai automaticamente dentro de `<span>descricaoSYS</span>`. Acho que tenho que criar uma classe, pois não posso remover todos os `p` do site.

Comment: @FelipeStoker Na página do jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) há um exemplo que retira a tag `p` se somente for parente de uma *div* veja se é algo como aquilo que você quer fazer.

Comment: é parecido sim,  mas não sei pq aqui n funciona

Comment: @FelipeStoker Conseguiu obter êxito?